# TFS: Sprints scheduling

Tags: tfs, data-warehouse, olap-cube

Is there a way to **track changes in sprints scheduling** in TFS?

for example:

sprint 1 start date=1/4/2015 ,  end date 10/4/2015

then change dates to:

start date=1/4/2015 , end date 20/4/2015

Can I track the changes of sprint scheduling in **Database**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are the dates changing? Audit of the date in TFS does not protect the sprint. You need to educate the developement team and the product owner that this is a bad idea and why...

Answer (score 0):

There is no audit of third information. However, permission k is restricted to team admins. Remove people that are messing with the dates, or that you don't trust from that list.